# Google Query on the results from unique function

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets and applied a UNIQUE function on a set of columns and want to apply a query function to take couple of columns and all rows from the the results to a different sheet, but I am getting blanks.

Can you please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Does the Query function not work on the results from UNIQUE function?

Comment: Best you show some formulas you are using or better still include a link to a test sheet.

Comment: You might need to change writing the columns as A,B,C to Col1,Col2,Col3

Comment: Tried that too but it still doesn't work, it shows blank. It might be same as when we copy and paste the results of the QUERY it doesn't list out the data properly till we do "Paste Special".

Answer (score 0):

Open or create a sheet.

Select a cell.

Type = followed by the sheet name, an exclamation point (!), and the cell being copied.

> For example, =`Sheet1!A1` or ='`Sheet number two'!B4`.

Note: If a sheet name contains spaces or other non-alphanumeric symbols, include single quotes around it (as in the second example).